# From Unbalanced to Balanced Panel

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I wand to fill in missing rows within a group, where a group is defined by a specific (id1,id2).

For instance I have a dataset with

```
  id1   id2  year  value
  33    29  1990     3.5
  33    29  1993     3.3
  33    29  1994     3.1
  32    28  1992     3.1
  32    28  1993     4.5
```

I would like to obtain the following dataset

```
 id1   id2  year   value
  33    29  1990     3.5
  33    29  1991      NA
  33    29  1992      NA
  33    29  1993     3.3
  33    29  1994     3.1
  32    28  1992     3.1
  32    28  1993     4.5
```

Note that row with `year==1991,year==1992` does not need to be created for the second group. The example is simplified, but the solution should work for strings/numerics, and for several value columns instead of just one.

Comment: And a group is defined by id1, or id1+id2? And you just want to have sequential years within a group but they can be totally non-overlapping across groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
require(data.table)
DT = data.table(id1 = c(33,33,33,32,32),
                id2 = c(29,29,29,28,28),  
               year = c(1990,1993,1994,1991,1992),
              value = c(3.5,3.3,3.1,3.1,4.5))


setkey(DT, id1,id2,year)
ans = DT[, list(year = seq.int(year[1L], year[.N])), by = list(id1,id2)]
ans = DT[setkey(ans)]
#    id1 id2 year value
# 1:  32  28 1991   3.1
# 2:  32  28 1992   4.5
# 3:  33  29 1990   3.5
# 4:  33  29 1991    NA
# 5:  33  29 1992    NA
# 6:  33  29 1993   3.3
# 7:  33  29 1994   3.1
```

Comment: Is there a way to add "by reference" these rows? I'd like to write it as a function that `set` these rows. The issue I face is that it is impossible to do something like `DT[ans,v:=1]` while keeping rows of `ans`.

Comment: Maybe `setkey(ans)[DT, \`:=\`(value = i.value, v = 1L)]`?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I'd like a function to be of the form `fill(DT,id,date)`, that modifies `DT` similarly to all the `set` functions. Your solution outputs a new dataset right?

Comment: Not sure I follow. But you can't add (or delete) rows *by reference* to data.tables *yet*, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: Exactly my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Arun: what does `setkey(ans)` do when no key is passed to it?

Comment: @Alex, it reorders the entire data set and sets key on *all* the columns.

Comment: @Arun , can you explain what `DT[setkey(ans)]` does? I never saw this syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here's maybe a fewer number of lines, but this is all done with standard data.frames (no data.table). Here's your sample data in `dput()` form

```
dd <- structure(list(id1 = c(33L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 32L), id2 = c(29L, 
29L, 29L, 28L, 28L), year = c(1990L, 1993L, 1994L, 1992L, 1993L
), value = c(3.5, 3.3, 3.1, 3.1, 4.5)), .Names = c("id1", "id2", 
"year", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

And i'll use a helper function to get rid of the ugly default rownames

```
unrowname <- function(x) `rownames<-`(x, NULL)
```

And then i transform the data with

```
do.call(rbind, unname(lapply(split(dd, interaction(dd$id1, dd$id2, drop=T)), function(x) {
    r = seq(from=min(x$year), to=max(x$year)); 
    cbind(unrowname(x[1,1:2]), year=r, value=x$value[match(r, x$year)])
})))
```

which gives

```
  id1 id2 year value
1  32  28 1992   3.1
2  32  28 1993   4.5
3  33  29 1990   3.5
4  33  29 1991    NA
5  33  29 1992    NA
6  33  29 1993   3.3
7  33  29 1994   3.1
```

so as long as you don't mind the row reshuffling, it should work fine.