# Fill in missing values by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If one wants to fill in missing values of a variable based on previous/posterior non NA observation within a group, the data.table command is

```
setkey(DT,id,date)
DT[, value_filled_in := DT[!is.na(value), list(id, date, value)][DT[, list(id, date)], value, roll = TRUE]]
```

which is quite complex. It's a shame since `roll` is a very fast and powerful option (esp compared with applying a function such as `zoo::na.locf` within each group)

I can write a convenience function to fill in missing values

```
   fill_na <-  function(x , by = NULL, roll =TRUE , rollends= if (roll=="nearest") c(TRUE,TRUE)
             else if (roll>=0) c(FALSE,TRUE)
             else c(TRUE,FALSE)){
    id <- seq_along(x)
    if (is.null(by)){
      DT <- data.table("x" = x, "id" = id, key = "id") 
      return(DT[!is.na(x)][DT[, list(id)], x, roll = roll, rollends = rollends, allow.cartesian = TRUE])

    } else{
      DT <- data.table("x" = x, "by" = by, "id" = id, key = c("by", "id")) 
      return(DT[!is.na(x)][DT[, list(by, id)], x, roll = roll, rollends = rollends, allow.cartesian = TRUE])
    }
  }
```

And then write

```
setkey(DT,id, date)
DT[, value_filled_in := fill_na(value, by = id)]
```

This is not really satisfying since one would like to write

```
setkey(DT,id, date)
DT[, value_filled_in := fill_na(value), by = id]
```

However, this takes a huge amount of time to run. And, for the end-user, it is cumbersome to learn that  `fill_na` should be called with the `by` option, and should not be used with `data.table` `by`.   Is there an elegant solution around this?

Some speed test

```
N <- 2e6
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(
         date = sample(10, N, TRUE),
           id = sample(1e5, N, TRUE),   
        value = sample(c(NA,1:5), N, TRUE),
       value2 = sample(c(NA,1:5), N, TRUE)                   
      )
setkey(DT,id,date)
DT<- unique(DT)

system.time(DT[, filled0 := DT[!is.na(value), list(id, date, value)][DT[, list(id, date)], value, roll = TRUE]])
#> user  system elapsed 
#>  0.086   0.006   0.105 
system.time(DT[, filled1 := zoo::na.locf.default(value, na.rm = FALSE), by = id])
#> user  system elapsed 
#> 5.235   0.016   5.274 
# (lower speed and no built in option like roll=integer or roll=nearest, rollend, etc)
system.time(DT[, filled2 := fill_na(value, by = id)])
#>   user  system elapsed 
#>  0.194   0.019   0.221 
system.time(DT[, filled3 := fill_na(value), by = id])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#> 237.256   0.913 238.405
```

Why don't I just use `na.locf.default` ? Even though the speed difference is not really important, the same issue arises for other kinds of data.table commands (those that rely on a merge by the variable in "by") - it's a shame to systematically ignore them in order to get an easier syntax. I also really like all the roll options.

Comment: How does the `na.locf` solution compare to this solution in terms of speed?

Comment: Is wrapping the entire thing (a la `dplyr::mutate`) not an option?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided code to [create a sample data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we could use to check our results and to help with benchmarking.

Comment: @ssdecontrol what do you mean?

Comment: If you get rid of the `::` call in the zoo one, it's about 30% faster for me.  i.e. call `na.locf.default` instead of `zoo::na.locf.default`

Comment: @GSee out of curiosity, why would that be the case?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Because `::` is a function and there is overhead associated with that extra function call.

Comment: @Matthew I mean, instead of writing a function you can call from inside `[.data.table`, what about a wrapper for the entire operation? But I realize now that a wrapper will probably end up making copies of `DT` (which defeats the purpose of a data.table).

Comment: @Matthew, it'd be great to be able to roll missing values directly in `data.table`. Could you please file an issue? Just linking back to this SO post is sufficient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is now a native `data.table` way of filling missing values (as of `1.12.4`).

This question spawned a github [issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/854) which was recently closed with the creation of functions `nafill` and `setnafill`. You can now use

```
DT[, value_filled_in := nafill(value, type = "locf")]
```

It is also possible to fill `NA` with a constant value or next observation carried back.

One difference to the approach in the question is that these functions currently only work on `NA` not `NaN` whereas `is.na` is `TRUE` for `NaN` - this is [planned](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4020) to be fixed in the next release through an extra argument.

I have no involvement with the project but I saw that although the github issue links here, there was no link the other way so I'm answering on behalf of future visitors.

Update: By default `NaN` is now treated same as `NA`.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a slightly faster and more compact way of doing it (version 1.9.3+):

```
DT[, filled4 := DT[!is.na(value)][DT, value, roll = T]]
```

Comment: My mistake! I thought that this would copy the whole table twice (once through `DT[!is.na(value)]`, the other through `X[Y]`), which would be problematic for a typical wide dataset. Isn't the case (at least for `DT[!is.na(value)]`)?

Comment: Ok. Subsetting columns in Y does not change anything. However, it seems `(DT[, filled4 := DT[!is.na(value), list(date,id,value)][DT, value, roll = T]]` is faster than your answer in a wide database

Comment: Hi @eddi. When I try your answer with `data.table 1.12.3` and OP's sample data it errors (`Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  :`). Do you know why? Cheers