# data.table selective non-match treatment during join: LOCF roll some columns and `na.fill` different columns

Tags: r, data.table

Let's have one irregular time series table, e.g. buy/sell transactions and resulting positions on stocks (here Apple):

```
library(data.table)
txns = data.table(Instrument=rep("AAPL", 3), 
                  Date=as.Date(c("2014-05-10","2014-05-15", "2014-05-20")),
                  Txn.Qty=c(100, -20, -30), # 
                  key=c("Instrument", "Date"))
txns[, Pos.Qty:=cumsum(Txn.Qty), by="Instrument"]
txns
#    Instrument       Date Txn.Qty Pos.Qty
# 1:       AAPL 2014-05-10     100     100
# 2:       AAPL 2014-05-15     -20      80
# 3:       AAPL 2014-05-20     -30      50
```

Then we want to track positions (and possibly daily valuation) in a second, mostly regular time-series table:

```
positions = data.table(Instrument=rep("AAPL", 13), 
                       Date=as.Date(setdiff(as.Date("2014-05-07") + 1:15, 
                                    txns$Date[1:2])), # gaps are possible
                       key=c("Instrument", "Date"))

out = merge(positions, txns, all=T)
out[!txns, Txn.Qty:=0]
out[, Pos.Qty:=zoo::na.locf(Pos.Qty, na.rm=F), by=Instrument] # `zoo` dependency
out
#    Instrument       Date Txn.Qty Pos.Qty
#  1:       AAPL 2014-05-08       0      NA
#  2:       AAPL 2014-05-09       0      NA
#  3:       AAPL 2014-05-10     100     100
#  4:       AAPL 2014-05-11       0     100
#  5:       AAPL 2014-05-12       0     100
#  6:       AAPL 2014-05-13       0     100
#  7:       AAPL 2014-05-14       0     100
#  8:       AAPL 2014-05-15     -20      80
#  9:       AAPL 2014-05-16       0      80
# 10:       AAPL 2014-05-17       0      80
# 11:       AAPL 2014-05-18       0      80
# 12:       AAPL 2014-05-19       0      80
# 13:       AAPL 2014-05-20     -30      50
# 14:       AAPL 2014-05-21       0      50
# 15:       AAPL 2014-05-22       0      50
```

I was hoping to speed up the above (i.e. roll last observation forward in some columns, fill non-joins with zeros for other columns) with a single, efficient join and `roll` argument, performing selectively only on *some* of the columns (similar to `.SDcols` philosophy).

Is it possible to achieve something like this using `data.table`'s `roll` argument on selected columns only?

Also, additional argument `fill` in `[.data.table` would help, equivalent to `na.fill` (we can think about `roll` corresponding to `na.locf`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171958/fill-in-missing-values-by-group-in-data-table?

Comment: @GSee thanks for link. It is related, however different situation: this Q is about handling _non-matches during the join of two tables_ (fill non-matches with zero?, mark them as NA? roll locf?, omit them?) the linked Q in contrast handles _NAs in a single table_, where those NAs might or might not be a result of previous non-match during join.

Comment: Edited the title to better describe the problem. Perhaps more related to `nomatch` argument in `[.data.table`

Comment: Thanks for filing it as a FR. Seems interesting, but also probably hard ;-).