# r - assigning conditional consecutive variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to:

```
Name, Day, Score, Diff
Jain, 1, 8, 0
Jain, 2, 6, -2
Jain, 3, 8, 2
Jain, 4, 12, 4
Jain, 5, 13, 1
Jain, 6, 6, -7
Matt, 1,4, 0
Matt, 2, 10, 6
Matt, 3, 11, 1
Matt, 4, 12, 1
Matt, 5, 5, -7
Matt, 6, 6, 1
```

I want to add a new column which will record "Off" when a score difference drops 3 points, until there's a gain of +3 points, which will then record "On" until there's a drop.

Example:

```
Name, Day, Score, Diff, OnOff
Jain, 1, 8, 0, "Off"
Jain, 2, 6, -2, "Off"
Jain, 3, 8, 2, "Off"
Jain, 4, 12, 4, "On"
Jain, 5, 13, 1, "On"
Jain, 6, 6, -7, "Off"
Matt, 1,4, 0, "Off"
Matt, 2, 10, 6, "On"
Matt, 3, 11, 1, "On"
Matt, 4, 12, 1, "On"
Matt, 5, 5, -7, "Off"
Matt, 6, 6, 1, "Off"
```

Can't seem to figure out how to code this one. I've attempted with the following:

```
df$OnOff <- ifelse(df$Diff >= 3, "On", ifelse(df$Diff <= -3, "Off", ""))
df$OnOff <- ifelse(df$OnOff == "", lag(df$OnOff), df$OnOff)
```

Comment: Based on the first 3 rows, why it is `Off`, there is no absolute drop to 3 points

Comment: I'd like it to assume it's "Off" until there's a +3 gain somewhere to trigger it to "On"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in the changes, then use `zoo::na.locf` (or similar) to fill in the blanks. Calling your data `dd`:

```
dd$OnOff = NA
dd$OnOff[1] = "off"
dd$OnOff[dd$Diff >= 3] = "on"
dd$OnOff[dd$Diff <= -3] = "off"
dd$OnOff = zoo::na.locf(dd$OnOff)
dd
#    Name Day Score Diff OnOff
#  1: Jain   1     8    0   off
#  2: Jain   2     6   -2   off
#  3: Jain   3     8    2   off
#  4: Jain   4    12    4    on
#  5: Jain   5    13    1    on
#  6: Jain   6     6   -7   off
#  7: Matt   1     4    0   off
#  8: Matt   2    10    6    on
#  9: Matt   3    11    1    on
# 10: Matt   4    12    1    on
# 11: Matt   5     5   -7   off
# 12: Matt   6     6    1   off
```

You don't mention grouping in the question, but you can use `dplyr` or `data.table` to do the `locf` by `Name` if needed.

To do things by name, you'll need to set the first row of each name to the default `'off'`. See Melissa's solution for a `dplyr` method. With `data.table` it looks like this:

```
setdt(dd)
dd[, OnOff := c('off', rep(NA, .N - 1)), by = Name]
dd[Diff >= 3, OnOff := "on"]
dd[Diff <= -3, OnOff := "off"]
dd[, OnOff := zoo::na.locf(OnOff), by = Name]
```

---

Using this data:

```
dd = data.table::fread("Name, Day, Score, Diff
Jain, 1, 8, 0
Jain, 2, 6, -2
Jain, 3, 8, 2
Jain, 4, 12, 4
Jain, 5, 13, 1
Jain, 6, 6, -7
Matt, 1,4, 0
Matt, 2, 10, 6
Matt, 3, 11, 1
Matt, 4, 12, 1
Matt, 5, 5, -7
Matt, 6, 6, 1")
```

Comment: How would I add in the by name for this? And thank you this worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Edited to include the "by name" code for `data.table`. See Melissa's answer for `dplyr` equivalent.

Comment: For a zoo-less data.table option, the last line can change to `dd[, OnOff := first(OnOff), by=rleid(Name, cumsum(!is.na(OnOff)))]`, I think.

Comment: @Frank interesting and clever, but much less clear and maybe slower? Guess it depends how much you hate extra dependencies.

Comment: Heh, yeah, I do this sort of thing (or even a rolling join `dd[, OnOff := dd[!is.na(OnOff), .(Name, Day, OnOff)][.SD, on=.(Name, Day), roll = TRUE, x.OnOff]]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181795), but don't know that I'd recommend it to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `tidyverse` solution using `fill`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(
    OnOff = case_when(
      1:n() == 1 ~ 'Off',
      Diff < -2 ~  "Off",
      Diff >2 ~ "On",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_)
  ) %>%
  fill(OnOff)
```

doing it by name:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(
    OnOff = case_when(
      1:n() == 1 ~ 'Off',
      Diff < -2 ~  "Off",
      Diff >2 ~ "On",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_)
  ) %>%
  fill(OnOff)
```

Comment: I think you don't need the temporary `row` column, you can just use `1:n() == 1 ~ 'Off'` directly. Saves the trouble of cleaning it up afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

One can write a simple function that traverse on `Diff` to compare value in order to switch between `On` and `Off` as:

```
#Function to decide On/Off logic
getOnOff <- function(x){
  lstVal <- "Off"
  value <- rep(NA,length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    if(x[i] >= 3){
      lstVal = "On"
    }else if(x[i] <= -3){
      lstVal = "Off"
    }
    value[i] <- lstVal
  }
  value
}

#Now use the function with `dplyr` to after grouping on Name

library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(OnOff = getOnOff(Diff))


# # A tibble: 12 x 5
# # Groups: Name [2]
# Name    Day Score  Diff OnOff
# <chr> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
# 1 Jain      1     8     0 Off  
# 2 Jain      2     6    -2 Off  
# 3 Jain      3     8     2 Off  
# 4 Jain      4    12     4 On   
# 5 Jain      5    13     1 On   
# 6 Jain      6     6    -7 Off  
# 7 Matt      1     4     0 Off  
# 8 Matt      2    10     6 On   
# 9 Matt      3    11     1 On   
# 10 Matt      4    12     1 On   
# 11 Matt      5     5    -7 Off  
# 12 Matt      6     6     1 Off
```

**Option#2:** Probably OP has not meant to switch on absolute count of different condition but if that is needed then one can try using `cumsum` with `dplyr`. The occurrence of `Diff >= 3` means count goes `up` and `Diff <= -3` means count goes `down`. The cumulative sum of these will give relative count on which `On/Off` can be decided.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(OnOff = ifelse(cumsum(Diff >= 3) - (cumsum(Diff<= -3))>0, "On","Off"))

#    Name Day Score Diff OnOff
# 1  Jain   1     8    0   Off
# 2  Jain   2     6   -2   Off
# 3  Jain   3     8    2   Off
# 4  Jain   4    12    4    On
# 5  Jain   5    13    1    On
# 6  Jain   6     6   -7   Off
# 7  Matt   1     4    0   Off
# 8  Matt   2    10    6    On
# 9  Matt   3    11    1    On
# 10 Matt   4    12    1    On
# 11 Matt   5     5   -7   Off
# 12 Matt   6     6    1   Off
#
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
Name, Day, Score, Diff
Jain, 1, 8, 0
Jain, 2, 6, -2
Jain, 3, 8, 2
Jain, 4, 12, 4
Jain, 5, 13, 1
Jain, 6, 6, -7
Matt, 1,4, 0
Matt, 2, 10, 6
Matt, 3, 11, 1
Matt, 4, 12, 1
Matt, 5, 5, -7
Matt, 6, 6, 1",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: I guess the condition is wrong. If I meet one of the criteria a couple times in a row, the other criterion won't stop the sequence. Eg, `data.frame(Diff = c(3, 3, -3, 3)) %>% mutate(OnOff = ifelse(cumsum(Diff >= 3) - (cumsum(Diff<= -3))>0, "On","Off"))` should have Off on row 3

Comment: @Frank I agree with comment. Let me try to look for a correction.

Comment: @Gregor Sorry, I didn't notice your advice. I agree `fill` based solutions could be appropriate choice but I have added an `custom function` based solution as an option.