# How to FILL DOWN (autofill) value , eg replace NA with first value in group, using data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, autofill

Very simple and common task:
I need to FILL DOWN in `data.table`  (similar to autofill function in MS Excel) so that

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"Paul 32
NA    45
NA    56
John  1
NA    5
George 88
NA    112")
```

becomes

```
Paul 32
Paul 45
Paul 56
John 1
John 5
George 88
George 112
```

Thank you!

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value) helps.

Comment: Brilliant idea - to treat data as a timeseries! And  then indeed there are various approaches to impute NA in ts!

Comment: Originally, this question had two example to resolve. The second one was later removed - to simply the question.  It is shown below. The answer to it was given below. EXAMPLE 2:    

DT <- fread(
"Paul, 1
Paul, 2 
Paul, NA 
Paul, NA 
John, 100
John, 110
John, NA
John, NA")

becomes

Paul 1
Paul 2 
Paul 3 
Paul 4 
John 100
John 110
John 120
John 130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the best way to do this is to use @Rui Barradas idea of the `zoo` package.  You can simply do it in one line of code with the `na.locf` function.

```
library(zoo)
DT[, V1:=na.locf(V1)]
```

Replace the V1 with whatever you name your column after reading in the data with fread. Good luck!

Comment: This neatly resolves Example 1. Once I write a code for Example 2, I'll post it here. Thanks!

Comment: Related solution: replacing NA's with `0`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table: ` for (i in names(DT))    
    DT[is.na(get(i)), (i):=0]`

Comment: Another way is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171958/fill-in-missing-values-by-group-in-data-table - `DT[, filled4 := DT[!is.na(value)][DT, value, roll = T]]`. But I could not make it to run on my example ;(

Answer (score 1):

For example 2, you can consider using `stats::spline` for extrapolation as follows:

```
DT2[is.na(V2), V2 := 
    as.integer(DT2[, spline(.I[!is.na(V2)], V2[!is.na(V2)], xout=.I[is.na(V2)]), by=.(V1)]$y)]
```

output:

```
     V1  V2
1: Paul   1
2: Paul   2
3: Paul   3
4: Paul   4
5: John 100
6: John 110
7: John 120
8: John 130
```

data:

```
DT2 <- fread(
"Paul, 1
Paul, 2 
Paul, NA 
Paul, NA 
John, 100
John, 110
John, NA
John, NA")
```

Comment: This is the answer for a more general Autofill solution, which was originally  asked in  EXAMPLE 2 of  this question, and later removed from question, which is 

DT <- fread(
"Paul, 1
Paul, 2 
Paul, NA 
Paul, NA 
John, 100
John, 110
John, NA
John, NA")

becomes

Paul 1
Paul 2 
Paul 3 
Paul 4 
John 100
John 110
John 120
John 130